# How to match curve path to reference photo

Tags: bezier-curves

Is there any easy way to create a curve that matches or closely resembles a imported svg such as this one?
[image: Imported SVG which defaults to curve object]

This is not the type of curve object I want, because it doesn't allow for start and end mapping. How do I get the curve to have more of a path structure than a profile structure? I could start with a circle curve and keep extruding the vertices and rotating them and scaling them but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

[image: Notice the handles are not conducive to a path that starts and ends]

[image: This is an attempt at creating a new curve path that can then use start and end mapping, with a round bevel, to create the desired shape in animation]

Comment: Why not tracing that image with vector graphics redactor (or skipping that if you have svg) and importing svg? If you want to invert what is filled on curve and what is empty, create a circle around main curve in Edit mode and position it so it encompasses the curve from svg

Answer (score 14):

You can create 4 circles mesh

[image]

Then delete vertices, connect and subdivide

[image]

Then go to object menu > convert > curve, and extrude as you like.

[image]

Comment: +1. This answer shows that it needs pure thinking not just software (or asking at blender.SE :) )